# MediaWiki: VisualEditor не дружит с шаблонами

Tags: mediawiki

После установки последней версии MediaWiki (1.37.1) никак не получается подружить встроенный в нее VisualEditor (VE) c шаблонами. Без шаблонов VE работает прекрасно. Также VE позволяет первоначально вставить шаблон в статью. Но если попытаться отредактировать с помощью VE статью, в которую ранее уже был вставлен шаблон, то при начале редактирования выпадает ошибка "Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server (HTTP 500)". При этом стандартный редактор wiki разметки работает с шаблонами в статьях корректно.
И еще одно наблюдение - если с помощью стандартного редактора удалить шаблон из статьи, то VE будет снова редактировать данную статью нормально.

Другими словами наличие в коде статьи wiki разметки {{код шаблона}} вызывает сбой в работе VE.

Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным и сумел решить проблему прошу поделиться решениями
Заранее спасибо!

p.s. в плане серверной части полный чайник, поэтому прошу сильно не пинать

Comment: Если HTTP 500, значит нужно читать в логах php на сервере, на что конкретно он там ругается

Comment: К сожалению, на хостинге говорят что при воспроизведении моей ошибки ничего не логируется ((

Comment: Тогда попробуйте посмотреть содержимое ответа 500 через инструменты разработчика в браузере, в мониторинге сети, вдруг там что-то дельное есть

Comment: Из чего-то понятного мне в мониторинге сети при воспроизведении ошибки нашел следующее  - в файле api.php  - {
    "error": {
        "code": "apierror-visualeditor-docserver-http",
        "info": "Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server (HTTP 500)",
        "docref": "See https://wikiarticle.ru/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/postorius/lists/mediawiki-api-announce.lists.wikimedia.org/&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."
    }
}